# Encrypt a Chrome-extension from not exposing to users

Tags: jquery

Anyway to encrypt a Chrome-extension from not exposing the source code?
we can do using obfuscate but form 1 Oct 2018, google removed extension.

https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-to-no-longer-allow-chrome-extensions-that-use-obfuscated-code/

can anyone suggest how can I encrypt my chrome extension to avoid user can see my code.

Comment: Encryption is a form of obfuscation, which they don't allow. What kind of solution are you expecting?

Comment: If the code can be ran on the browsers PC, the user can potentially view the code regardless of how hard you want to make it be to do so. Normal users are not going to be looking at the code. The people who know where to look would also know how to run the dis-encryption code on the source code that your code points to as the step before running the code. It is also better for normal users that the code not be encrypted so anti malware software can look at it.

Comment: I want to avoid to user can take my code and use so is there anyway is there to user can not see my code. means encrypt, i dont want to use any web service for that.

Answer (score 1):

One method is that don't upload your extension on Chrome web store.
Second is that host js files anywhere elese and put script including tags in your extension code and include that js files.